# jQuery: How to callback/restore after remove checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This is my html code:

```
<div class="foo">
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       One<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Two<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Three<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Four<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
</div>    

<button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="allFinished">Remove checked</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="show">Show</button>
```

This is my jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#allFinished').on("click", function(){
      $(".checkbox-wrapper").each(function(){           
          if($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked")){ $(this).remove(); } 
      });
  });

  $('#show').on("click", function(){
      //I don't know what must I fill this
  });
});
```

I know how to remove the checkbox after check and click button. but I don't know how to restore it again? anybody can help me
This demo from fiddle [DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/akatipen/3askfpam/)

Comment: What is condition for `input type="checkbox"` to be shown ?

Comment: does it have to be removed? or can you `.hide()` it instead?  Otherwise, you're going to have to use `.append()` to put a new checkbox in there.  You've essentially deleted the checkbox

Comment: use hide() no problem. when use hide() how to show again? but when use hide() I want the value will be checked=false

Comment: use `.show()` to show it

Comment: when use show() what condition to make it show again when the values all checked=false ?

Comment: Do you really want to *remove* them, or just *un-check* them, which seems more the logical thing to do?  I think you may have confused the two.

Comment: un-check them and don't show it. When click `button show` it will be shown all again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your last comment: [*"un-check them and don't show it. When click button show it will be shown all again"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638756/jquery-how-to-callback-restore-after-remove-checkbox/33639430#comment-55052480), this solution should do the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#allFinished').on("click", function(){
      $('.checkbox-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).parent().hide();
  });

  $('#show').on("click", function(){
      $('.checkbox-wrapper:hidden').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       One<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Two<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Three<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-wrapper">
       Four<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 </label>
</div>    

<button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="allFinished">Remove checked</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="show">Show</button>
```

The above solution is simply but I think it does what you want.

Comment: thank you mr @War10ck it solved my problem what I want, its make me have idea. I added script `$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);` to make it un-check. It will be not append a table, then will be show again use `('.checkbox:hidden').show();` @War10ck

Comment: @Stfvns Great! Glad this worked for you. I'd recommed using `.prop('checked', false);` in place of `.attr('checked', false);` since `checked` is really a property not an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore a deleted node. So, you can just hide it when you fire remove action, or save node complexity in a cloned variable and inject it later with methods like appendChild or setting html content.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.filter()` , `.find()` , `.add()` , `Array.prototype.sort()` to reset elements to original index when appended to parent element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var clone;
  $('#allFinished').on("click", function () {
      var checked = $('.checkbox-wrapper').filter(":has(:checked)")
                    .find(":checked").prop("checked", false).parent().remove();
      // if elements already removed , add current removed element to `clone` stack
      if (clone) {
        clone = clone.add(checked)
      // else set `clone` to initial element removed
      } else {
        clone = checked
      }        
    });

    $('#show').on("click", function () {
        if (clone) {
          var elems = $(".foo label").add(clone)
          .toArray()
          .sort(function(a, b) {
            return $("input", a)[0].name < $("input",b)[0].name ? 0 : 1 
          });
          $(".foo").html(elems);
          // set `clone` to `undefined`
          clone = void 0;
        } else {
           console.log("no checked inputs removed")
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3askfpam/9/

Comment: thanks it almost what i want. what I want when click `button show` will be shown all again. in your update when I click `button removed checked` 2 times, the `button show` just show back removed from the second click not it all

Comment: @Stfvns _"when I click button removed checked 2 times, the button show just show back removed from the second click not it all"_ See updated post ; used `.add()` in first `click` handler

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3askfpam/2/) a working solution with .show() and .hide().

```
$(".checkbox-wrapper").each(function(){
  if($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked")){                         
     $(this).show(); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should hide and disable you checkbox, that way your server side script won't "get" the value. At least in php it won't